# Sublime 3 JS Snippets to Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, sublimetext3, code-snippets

I have a lot of useful snippets on JS.
Like `cl` for `console.log();` or

`fn` for

```js
function methodName (arguments) {
    // body...
}
```

However I can't use them on `*.ts` files.

How can manage the snippets and complation for js to ts also.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add a typescript source to your snippets scope.

```
<scope>source.js, source.ts</scope>
```

There is a exemple of snippet that you can find in the TypeScript package:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
class ${2:ClassName}${3: extends ${4:AnotherClass}} {
    $5
    ${6:constructor}(${7:argument}) {
        ${0:// code...}
    }
}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>class</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.ts</scope>
    <description>class …</description>
</snippet>
```

Comment: thnx for reply, where can i find these files. `*.sublime-package` files are binary.

Comment: @engincancan Just FYI the *.sublime-package are actually zip files. You can use 7zip or any other tools to view and unzip them